# BeautifulSoup : Fetched all the links on a webpage how to navigate through them without selenium?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to write a mediocre script to download subtitles from one particular website as y'all can see. I'm a newbie to beautifulsoup, so far I have a list of all the "href" after a search query(GET). So how do I navigate further, after getting all the links?
Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

usearch = input("Movie Name? : ")
url = "https://www.yifysubtitles.com/search?q="+usearch
print(url)
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    dictn = link.get('href')
    print(dictn)
```

Comment: it's not that simple. You don't get directly the url of subtitles here. just search result. Then you click on that result then you click on download subtitle then .....

Comment: True. But what I was thinking was to navigate through all the "href"s that have been fetched with the request.get method and souping them up again and so on

Comment: You have to navigate each link one by one then fetch data and store it some where then go further

Comment: @Abdullah Ahmed Ghaznavi yes exactly, but the thing is how to navigate through all the links? Any specific method? Can you show an example code snippet for the same? I'm trying to use the requests.get method again right now.

Comment: Well for this i have an idea first stores all the links that you are fetching from this code into a list then use selenium and click on each link then perform the same operation of fetching data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `resp.text` instead of `resp.content`
Try this to get the search results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url_f = "https://www.yifysubtitles.com"
search_url = base_url_f + "/search?q=last+jedi"
resp = requests.get(search_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
for media in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "media-body"}):
    print(base_url_f + media.find('a')['href'])
```

out: https://www.yifysubtitles.com/movie-imdb/tt2527336

Comment: It does seem perfectly sound, since you pin-pointed the class which has our desired href. Will give it a go and revert

Comment: When you finish please share it here so that It can help.

Comment: Indeed, I will.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! I'll add an "Edit" section to the question and add the modified code.

Comment: Ask separate question instead.